# How to iterate through data frame and edit values?

Tags: python, pandas

Google provided me with the code:

```py
for i in df.index:
    df.at[i, 'job'] = 0 if df.at[i, 'job'] == 'unemployed' else 1
```

But python says: `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: As Jan has pointed out, you don't need to iterate over the rows. I would use a Boolean series instead:
`df['job'] = (df.job != 'unemployed').astype(int)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to iterate over the rows. You can use `apply()`:

```
df['job'] = df['job'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x == 'unemployed' else 1)
```

Or you can use `numpy`'s `where`:

```
df['job'] = np.where(df['job']=='unemployed', 1, 0)
```

Or as Arne pointed out in his comment, you can convert the boolean result of the comparison to int:

```
df['job'] = (df.job != 'unemployed').astype(int)
```

Comment: Don't use `apply` in this context. It's inefficient